# how to map a single value over an array of predicates?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

If I have an array of predicate functions,

```
rules = [is_cute, has_good_job, is_not_crazy, is_tall_enough ]
```

what is the best practice to apply all of them on the same variable?

what I've come out with is

```
candidate= "joe pesci"
_.map(rules, function(rule){return rule.apply(candidate)} )
```

clearly the aim is to use that into something like

```
it_is_true_love = _.all( rules.map(...))
```

is this a good thing to do? am I missing something? what are other ways to do this in functional programming?

Comment: Please, set language in the labels.

Comment: I was not using any language in particular. I did not think it is important for the question. It is currently pseudo-code,  js inspired. I Can change it to valid js, but it loses in readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most elegant solution I've found so far is with [Rambda.js](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#allPass):

```
var rules = [is_cute, has_good_job, is_not_crazy, is_tall_enough ]
var is_true_love = R.allPass(rules);
```

example usage:

```
// is_true_love('joe pesci') => false //not that cute anymore
// is_true_love('elon musk') => false //he's probably crazy!
// is_true_love( the_real_one ) => true
```

Answer (score 2):

If the aim is to check if every or some are true then you can use:

```js
rules.every(function(rule){return rule.apply(candidate)})
rules.some(function(rule){return rule.apply(candidate)})
```

I'm not sure which Algol language you are writing in. Looks like JavaScript so I guess you need to use `return` in your example for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

As with most "for-like" problems, you can use map with lambda.

Example written in Elixir language (note that the dot here is a function application):

```
bigger_than = fn x,y -> x>y end
bigger_1 = fn x -> bigger_than.(x,1) end
bigger_5 = fn x -> bigger_than.(x,5) end
bigger_10 = fn x -> bigger_than.(x,10) end

# list of predicates
l = [bigger_1,bigger_5,bigger_10]

# results in an interactive session:
iex(7)> x=1
iex(8)> Enum.map(l,fn f -> f.(x) end)
[false, false, false]
iex(9)> Enum.map(l,fn f -> f.(1) end)
[false, false, false]
iex(10)> Enum.map(l,fn f -> f.(3) end)
[true, false, false]
iex(11)> Enum.map(l,fn f -> f.(7) end)
[true, true, false]
iex(12)> Enum.map(l,fn f -> f.(11) end)
[true, true, true]
```